# Abundant numbers list in Python

Tags: python-3.x

Working in python I need to return a list of the first n abundant numbers in ascending order. An abundant number is an integer that is less than the sum of its perfect divisors. For example, 12 is an abundant number because its perfect divisors (1, 2, 3, 4, and 6) add up to 16.
The function abundant(n) should return a list containing exactly the first n abundant numbers in ascending order. For example, abundant(7) would return a list with the first seven abundant numbers.

I have tried to use:

```
def abundant(n):
    def factors(value):
        factors = [x for x in range(1, value + 1 // 2 + 1) if value % x == 0]
        return factors
        if sum(factors) > value:
            return value
        abundant = factors()
        return abundant[:n]
```

Comment: And what have you tried? What isn't working? Stack Overflow isn't a code-writing service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not an expert in python, but I'd recommend a for loop, so:

```
 # From 1 to 10

 n = 0
 for i in range(10):
         n = n + 1
         abundant(n)
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

No need to return the abn list as it is declared as global

```
abn=[]  #to store abundant nos.
def factors(n):
    s=1 
    if n==1:
        return 1
    if n%2==0:
        step=1
    else:
        step=2

    r=int(n**.5)

    if(r**2==n):
        r-=1
        s+=r+1
        # s-sum 
    f=2
    #print("n= ",n)
    while(f<=r):
        if n%f==0:
            s+=f+n//f
            #print(f,n//f)
        if(s>n):
            abn.append(n)   #if sum is going to be greater than n iam storing them in abn list
            return n
        f+=step    
    else:
        return 0

n=int(input())
for i in range(12,n+1):  #since 12 is the first abn. no the range starts from 12
    factors(i)

abn.sort()
print("abn. nos list: ",abn)
```